# How can I clearcontents with Range(cells..) instead of range("A1...)

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing the good old runtime error 1004 with the following code

```
Worksheets("abc").Range(Cells(4, 9), Cells(15, 9)).ClearContents
```

I have tried
`Worksheets("abc").Range("I4:I15").ClearContents` and it works.

The reason why I need the Range(Cells(...)) format is because I actually write

```
Worksheets("abc").Range(Cells(4, 9), Cells(Max, 9)).ClearContents
```

So I want to control the range via a variable. For me the error doesn't make any sense, but well with Excel you never know ;)

Comment: Is the sheet protected?

Comment: `Cells(4, 9)` is not qualified so will apply to the active sheet, not necessarily "abc".

Comment: @SJR I've had a lot of trouble with that specific interaction. VBA tries to build a range in one sheet but using cell objects from a different sheet, which gives `Runtime error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed`. This is very likely the issue.

Comment: `With Worksheets("abc")`, `.Range(.Cells(4, 9), .Cells(Max, 9)).ClearContents`, `End With`. Note the periods `.` in front of `Range` and `Cells`.